# Title from blog article in static page

Tags: php, flat-file

assuming I am not an expert in php, I still wanted to ask you how to get the title dynamically from a code that I insert in the static page from a blog using the "include" function, in practice the title in the blog template is "{title}"

Comment: We would need to see some code how that works.  There are infinite ways to implement templates.  Chances are you have it and just don't know it, you can do `print_r(get_defined_vars())`  Which makes an array out of all the defined variables in the current scope, to see.

Comment: <?php
        $template = "blog";
        include("D:\\inetpub\\webs\\mysite\\news\\show_news.php");
    ?>

Comment: How or what is `title` in this file `show_news.php` for example is it `$title`?  if it's a normal variable you will be able to access it after the include statement, like any variable.